# Keep UILabel centered using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I'm trying to keep my UILabel centered horizontally. I have tried in IB setting leading and trailing, but that simply stretches out the entire label, and I need it to stay the same size.  Everything is set up using Editor and the Pin function in IB and not coding.  Suggestions?

[image][image]

Comment: Which `UILabel` are you talking about?

Comment: Which UILabel are you trying to center? Have you tried Editor menu > Align > Horizontal Center in Container?

Comment: Align Horizontal Center will get it centered for that orientation, not anything to do with this.  I'm talking about the label that has 07 in the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the time buttons together and aligned to the center.  Put them all in their own view, arrange how you wish.  Then fix the length and width of the view and center it in the container like Aaron suggested.  I do believe you will need to make one more constraint.  Perhaps pin the view to the top.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but there HAS to be an easier way than creating a separate view inside another view just to keep them all centered.

Comment: Try this.  Pin the center button with the 07 to the center of the container.  Also pin it to the top of the view.  This will keep it in the position you want.  Make sure to also pin width and height.  Then put the other buttons on the sides one at a time. For the ten button, drag it towards the 07 until you get it to snap into place.  That will make a constraint.  Adjust this constraint to your desired distance between buttons.  Pin width and height.  Do the same for the 52 button.  Then do the same for the months and seconds.  What you are doing is grouping them all to the center button.

Comment: Only thing @Douglas is that I need that space to be variable...closer together when in portrait and further apart when horizontal.

Comment: You might want to try this tutorial.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2  It does something that is similar to what you want.  But you might have to pin the middle one like I said, then pin the two sides buttons to the edges.  After you put the rest of the buttons in, make the constraints between them greater or less than so they will change.  Make sure you pin width and height of all buttons. Finally change the priority of the constraints in between the buttons. Do this in the right hand pane.  But make them all the same like 999 or something.

Comment: Those tutorials don't have anything for how to set multiple labels to stay equidistant from each other relative to the orientation.

Comment: Well, they go over how to make variable constraints.  Thought it might help.

Comment: One other thought.  Can you pin the middle one in place, then pin the ones on the sides to the sides.  Then pin the days and the minutes to the left and right sides respectfully.  Define those two constraints and change them upon orientation change with NSConstraint setConstant##.

Answer (score 0):

Seems too obvious, but did you try nsconstraint of width = XXX.  Label should say same width and the leading trailing should keep it put.

Comment: That's the issue.  I don't want them pinned to the superview.  Then when I go to the landscape mode, the labels are not all equidistant from each other.  The center one is centered and the others are all too much pinned.

Comment: have you tried setting the leading and trailing of each 'time' label  to the label next to it?

Comment: Yes...then I end up getting them all stuck together on one side of the screen or the other.

Answer (score 0):

For keeping a UILabel horizontally centre, add the following constraints:-

1. Width constraint to the label.
2. Height constraint to the label.
3. Top/Bottom Constraint for placing the label vertically.
4. Horizontal centre in container.